# How to solve $x^{x^x}=(x^x)^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can we solve the equation :

$x^{x^x}=(x^x)^x$
with $x \in {\mathbb{R}+}^*$

Thanks for heping me :)

Comment: Simplify the RHS. Then equate exponents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no $x\in \mathbb R^+$ aside from $1$ or $2$ that satisfies the equation. It is fairly easy to see this. Assume that $x$ is not $1$ or $2$. Then, $x$ is non-zero.
Write $$x^{x^x}=(x^x)^x$$
As $$x^{x^x}=x^{x^2}$$
Since $x$ is non-zero, we may divide both side by $x^{x^2}$:
$$x^{x^x-x^2}=1$$
Since $x\in \mathbb R^+$, we must then have $x^x-x^2=0\implies x^x=x^2$- the only other possibility is $x=1$ which we have assumed not to be true.
We may again use the fact that $x$ is non-zero to divide both sides by $x^2$. This gives us $$x^{x-2}=1$$

Again, we're working in $\mathbb R^+$, so this must mean $x-2=0$ (we assumed $x\neq 1$), i.e. $x=2$ but this contradicts our initial assumption.

Comment: Should be "Since $x\in\mathbb R^2$ and $x\neq 1$ we must then have $x^x-x^2=0.$" It's true that $x^x-x^2=0$ when $x=1$ as well, but you can't prove that $x^y=1$ implies $y=0$ except when $x\neq 1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That is present in the parentheses- I'm not sure what you're objecting to

Answer (score 3):

We can check when the exponents are equal.

It is $x^{x^x}=(x^x)^x\Leftrightarrow x^{(x^x)}=x^{x^2}\Leftrightarrow x^x=x^2$

Now x^x-x^2=0\Leftrightarrow $x^2(x^{x-2}-1)=0$.

So $x^2=0$ or $x^{x-2}=1$.

Since $x\neq 0$ we have $x^{x-2}=1$ left, which holds if $x-2=0$. So $x=2$

And $2^{2^2}=2^{2\cdot 2}$

Edit: And x=1 is an obvious solution...

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as
$$x^{x^x}=x^{x^2}$$
$$x^x=x^2$$
$$x^{x-2}=1$$
$$\therefore x=1,2$$

Answer (score 1):

Applying $\log$ to both sides

$$
x^x\log x = x^2\log x\Rightarrow (x^x-x^2)\log x=0
$$

so we have $\log x= 0\Rightarrow x = 1$ and $x^x=x^2$ with two solutions $x = 1$ and $x = 2$ because following $x\log x = 2\log x\Rightarrow (x-2)\log x = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by noting $(x^x)^x=x^{2x}$, and then by comparing the exponents, since the exponential with base x is increasing.

(Note, writing ${x^x}^x$ is extremely ambiguous. Either you mean $(x^x)^x$ or $x^{(x^x)}$. In this case the context is clear, but in general it is safer to use brackets.)

Comment: $(x^x)^x=x^{x^2}$, not $x^{2x}.$

Comment: Also, as a rule, ${a^b}^c$ is taken to be $a^{(b^c)}$ in general since the other interpretation simplifies easily as $a^{bc}.$